# Google map API with JSON response some point need to decoded

Tags: python, google-maps-api, web-service

When I use Google map API with python, I  would like to know the path between the two points.
it response a JSON, but point need to be decoded.

example:

this is a set of point data : cq{oCqahzQDGr@iA

but how can I to decode this, making it become readable point coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has encryption for line tools. There are several decrpyting methods.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) is googles documentation and [here](https://gist.github.com/signed0/2031157) is one example for using in code.